# Service doesn't stop when calling stopSelf()

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a Service supposed to play music in background. I wanted it's notification to stop service, so I created a broadcast reciever that was supposed to call stopSelf() on notification click, but it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why. My code:

Service:

```
public class RadioService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

MediaPlayer radioPlayer;
String url = "radiourl";
String action;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;


public RadioService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    Log.e("Service", "Bind");

    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Log.e("Service", "onStart");
    action = intent.getAction();
    Log.e("ServiceAction", action);



    switch (action) {

        case "play":
        radioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        radioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            radioPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("setDataSource", e.toString());
        }

        radioPlayer.prepareAsync();
        radioPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        case "stop":
            stopSelf();

    }



    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer radioPlayer) {

    Log.e("Service", "onPrepared");
    radioPlayer.start();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle("Radio")
                    .setContentText("Press to stop playback");



    registerReceiver(stopServiceReceiver, new IntentFilter("myFilter"));
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("myFilter"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());


}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.e("Service", "onDestroy");

    if(notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    //Zwolnij mediaplayer
    if(radioPlayer != null && radioPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        radioPlayer.stop();
        radioPlayer.reset();
        radioPlayer.release();
    }


    super.onDestroy();
}

protected BroadcastReceiver stopServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        unregisterReceiver(stopServiceReceiver);
        stopSelf();
    }
};
}
```

Comment: I would use a local broadcast for this (assuming the broadcast doesn't have to leave the package) so you don't have to mess with the manifest .. Did you do any debugging? Do you know if your broadcast code is working and sending and receiving the broadcast? Debug it step by step, put something like a Log statement in your onReceive() method and see if your broadcast code is working. Pinpoint the issue more precisely and work from there ... just some hints, this is what I would do to troubleshoot

Comment: Thank You, I'll try to debug it more precisely, and if I find a solution I'll post it myself.